# Prove that if a transformation preserves inner product, then it is a linear transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

If a transformation `T` preserves inner product, then `T` it is a linear transformation.

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

Such a transformation sends $0$ to $0$, preserves the norm, and preserves orthogonality, thus it sends the standard basis  $e_1, \dotsc, e_n$ to an orthonormal frame, $d_1, \dotsc, d_n$ and now write an arbitrary vector $v = \sum a_i e_i.$ It will be mapped to $\sum a_i d_i.$ (since $\langle f(v), f(e_i)\rangle = \langle v, e_i\rangle.$ So, linear.